# How can I configure http basic auth in a web service accessed through Talend Open Studio?

Tags: web-services, http-authentication, talend

As an example, I have an About web-service, which only method getVersion return the application version.

I can easily call it through SoapUI :

[image]

But, accessing it through a Job in Talend seems impossible.

I tried the simplest one :

[image]

Configured with authentication checked and admin/**** as user/password.

however, each time I run my job, it ends with the following error

```
Démarrage du job About a 14:04 18/10/2013.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 4025
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tWebService_1
org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/digital-express-soap/AboutService?xsd=1
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:710)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.resolveXmlSchema(SchemaBuilder.java:706)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleImport(SchemaBuilder.java:538)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleSchemaElementChild(SchemaBuilder.java:1513)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleXmlSchemaElement(SchemaBuilder.java:659)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:540)
    at org.talend.webservice.helper.ServiceDiscoveryHelper.getSchemaCollection(ServiceDiscoveryHelper.java:363)
    at org.talend.webservice.helper.ServiceDiscoveryHelper.init(ServiceDiscoveryHelper.java:130)
    at org.talend.webservice.helper.ServiceDiscoveryHelper.<init>(ServiceDiscoveryHelper.java:90)
    at org.talend.webservice.helper.ServiceInvokerHelper.<init>(ServiceInvokerHelper.java:98)
    at test_lct.about_0_1.About.tWebService_1Process(About.java:300)
    at test_lct.about_0_1.About.runJobInTOS(About.java:559)
    at test_lct.about_0_1.About.main(About.java:425)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/digital-express-soap/AboutService?xsd=1
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:677)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:186)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:772)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection$2.run(XmlSchemaCollection.java:738)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection$2.run(XmlSchemaCollection.java:737)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.parseDoPriv(XmlSchemaCollection.java:736)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:705)
    ... 12 more
[statistics] disconnected
```

So it appears my server don't accept the provided auth. What is really strange, given that debugging my realm reveals that some authenticated calls are made. However, it also seems the last call is unauthorized. Why ?

**EDIT**

I did some more tests by enabling HTTP logging in Glassfish, then perform one test for each tool.

Using soapui, I get

```
"127.0.0.1" "NULL-AUTH-USER" "07/Nov/2013:10:45:51 +0100" "POST /digital-express-soap/AboutService HTTP/1.1" 401 1069 
"127.0.0.1" "admin" "07/Nov/2013:10:45:51 +0100" "POST /digital-express-soap/AboutService HTTP/1.1" 200 247
```

And using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration 5.3.1, I get

```
"127.0.0.1" "NULL-AUTH-USER" "07/Nov/2013:11:03:27 +0100" "POST /digital-express-soap/AboutService HTTP/1.1" 401 1069 
"127.0.0.1" "admin" "07/Nov/2013:11:03:27 +0100" "POST /digital-express-soap/AboutService HTTP/1.1" 200 247
```

which, as far as I know, is **exactly the same**. So the order in which queries are made to my server is the same, but the way the client interprets it change.

So my question can now be changed to "why Talend can't interpret correctly the 401 return from server when soapui can, considering both are based upon similar open-source web-services stacks ?"